# I am new to React and need some assistance regarding How can I embed a live video stream in react with following streaming code

Tags: reactjs

This is a script written in JavaScript that uses the JSMpeg library to display a video stream from a WebSocket server at the URL "ws://local-server:PORT". It also uses JQuery to measure the latency (or delay) of the video stream. The latency measurement is performed by setting an image source to the URL "http://local-server:PORT" and measuring the time it takes to receive a response (or an error) from the server. The latency measurement is repeated every 500ms by calling the "latency" function with the setTimeout method. The latency measurement is displayed in a

element with the id "timer".

Following is the code (from backend):

```html
<html>

<body onload="latency()">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <br>
  <div>
    <h1 style="color:black"><img id="junkOne" />Lantency (Client->Server):
      <p id="timer"></p>
      </h2>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsmpeg-player.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  player = new JSMpeg.Player('**ws**'://local-server:PORT', {
        canvas: document.getElementById('canvas') // Canvas should be a canvas DOM element    })
</script>
<script>
  function latency() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    $('#junkOne').attr('src', '**http**://local-server:PORT').error(function() {
      var end = new Date().getTime();
      $('#timer').html("" + (end - start) + "ms");
    });
    setTimeout(latency, 500);
  }
</script>
```

So, a live video stream is coming and I can see it by pasting this link ('http://local-host:PORT') in the browser, But I am unable to fetch this video in react for client.

I have tried different option like HTML video elements, React HLS library, React canvas but I can not embed this streaming in react.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import JSMpeg from 'jsmpeg-player';

    const VideoStream = () => {
    
        const videoRef = useRef(null);
        const [videos, setVideos] = useState()
    
      useEffect(() => {
        new JSMpeg.Player(`http://host:PORT/`, {
          canvas: videoRef.current,
        });
      }, []);
    
        return <>
            <canvas ref={videoRef} />
        </>
    }

export default VideoStream;
```

Comment: I recommend you look at this differently. Rather than embedding this code into React, you should consider refactoring this code completely as a React Component. The primary reason has to do with jQuery, which should really be avoided with React (you don't need it here to accomplish your latency timer goal), and the secondary reason has to do with managing the async requests being made. You'll find it much easier that way.

Comment: Well, that wasn't hard at all - a little bit of research goes a long way. From the author of JSMpeg-player comes [a react component demo app](https://github.com/cycjimmy/react-jsmpeg-player-demo).